# Question about complete metric on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I've recently been wondering about whether non-complete metrics on manifolds can be transformed into complete metrics on manifolds and whether all manifolds have complete metrics. After some googling I came across [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18844/does-every-smooth-manifold-of-infinite-topological-type-admit-a-complete-riemann) and the first comment says that any metric is actually conformal to a complete metric. I was wondering if anybody can show me a proof of this because I have had difficulty finding one. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

$\textbf{Theorem 1}$ of [The Existence of complete Riemannian Metrics](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0133785-8/S0002-9939-1961-0133785-8.pdf) is what you're looking for :

> For any Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ there exists a complete Riemannian metric which is conformal to $g$

The proof starts right on the first page.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to argue that every second countable differentiable manifold $M$ admits a complete Riemannian metric is the following:
By Whitney, $M$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ as a closed submanifold. The pullback metric on $M$ from $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ then is complete since closed subsets of complete metric spaces are complete.

Comment: Yes, but the complete metric you put in this way is unrelated to the one that was originally put on $M$. The question is whether there is a complete metric that is **conformal** to the given one.

Comment: "... and whether all manifolds have complete metrics" - that's what I answered!

Comment: Fair enough, the question was admittedly a bit unclear. +1